How to make the entire TOC of class memoir in sans-serif and in `light_blue`?
I have a tex file in class memoir
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  bookmarksopenlevel=3
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\definecolor{light_blue}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \chapter style 
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}% Chapter number/title in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}% Chapter page number in ToC
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{light_blue}}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{light_blue}}
\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \section style
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \subsection style

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}
\chapter*{Abstract}

\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=light_blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\tableofcontents*
\endgroup

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\section{Background}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some SDEs}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some PDEs}

\end{document}

The TOC is

Could you explain how to make the entire TOC in sans-serif and in light_blue? In above screenshot, the dots and the number are not light_blue.

You could switch to light_blue colour before the toc. As you anyway have a group around the toc, this won't change the content after the toc.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  bookmarksopenlevel=3
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\definecolor{light_blue}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \chapter style 
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}% Chapter number/title in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}% Chapter page number in ToC
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{light_blue}}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{light_blue}}
\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \section style
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \subsection style

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}
\chapter*{Abstract}

\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=light_blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\color{light_blue}\tableofcontents*
\endgroup

\chapter{Introduction}
test
\section{Motivation}
\section{Background}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some SDEs}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some PDEs}

\end{document}


Could you explain why \color{light_blue} does not have any effect without \hypersetup{linkcolor=light_blue}?

@Akira You are using hyperref. This makes parts of the toc clickable links which will have whatever colour you tell hyperref they should be.
